# Does FB.PublishInstall Require AuthToken?

Tags: facebook-unity-sdk

As far as I'm aware, most FB calls require that the user is logged in and has a valid authtoken.

**Questions**

1. Do FB.PublishInstall and FB.AppEvents.LogEvent require a valid authtoken?
2. Can I call FB.PublishInstall every time the app launches or do I have to track if I've ever called it and only call it once per install?
3. Do I even need to call PublishInstall or does this get taken care of automatically? From my reports on Facebook, it looks like I already see total installs and I'm not currently calling PublishInstall.

I'm using Unity 4.2.2 and Facebook SDK 4.3.6.

Thanks,
Colter

Comment: hey, did you find an answer to question no. 2?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, neither of these should need an access token.  PublishInstall mainly exists in case you want to mobile app install ads, but don't want to do a full Facebook integration.